# Get unique device ID

Tags: android, device

I use this method, but sometimes the result change for the same user on the same mobile:

```
                    sDeviceId = "35" + //we make this look like a valid IMEI
                    Build.BOARD.length() % 10 + Build.BRAND.length() % 10 +
                    (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP ? Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS[0].length() % 10 : Build.CPU_ABI.length() % 10) +
                    Build.DEVICE.length() % 10 +
                    Build.DISPLAY.length() % 10 + Build.HOST.length() % 10 +
                    Build.ID.length() % 10 + Build.MANUFACTURER.length() % 10 +
                    Build.MODEL.length() % 10 + Build.PRODUCT.length() % 10 +
                    Build.TAGS.length() % 10 + Build.TYPE.length() % 10 +
                    Build.USER.length() % 10 + //13 digits
                    Settings.Secure.getString(
                            MyApplication.getInstance().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID));
```

Have you got an idea guys? thank you very much!

Comment: some of the values you use can change, that's not a bug

Comment: Ok @VladyslavMatviienko, but could you give me which values exactly please ?

Comment: let's say most part of them, with the Android update, for example